# What's the significance of the grandfather clock in Elfen Lied?

Tags: elfen-lied

In the anime *Elfen Lied*, Kouta and Yuuka own a grandfather clock that, if I recall correctly, has been broken for quite some time prior to the start of the series. At the very end of the final episode, Kouta and Yuuka sit down (with Nana and Mayu, I believe) to start their new life... only for the grandfather clock to mysteriously start chiming, apropos of nothing, just as

> a figure implied to be Lucy approaches the front door.

I never understood what the deal was with the grandfather clock, and why it suddenly began working again at the end. I'm guessing that it must be symbolic of something, but I can't think what it might be symbolizing. If it's meant to symbolize Kouta moving on with his life, then

> Lucy apparently showing up again rather ruins that.

**What is the significance of the grandfather clock in *Elfen Lied*?**

Answer (score 4):

My personal interperation of the clock was always that it symbolizes the start of a normal live for Kouta and company. Which in place would fit really well with the ending of the rhyme [elfenlied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfenlied) which insinuates the 'elf' observing, hitting it's head on a stone with Cuckoo sounds.

> "What are those bright windows?
>   There must be a wedding inside;
>   The little people are sitting at the feast,
>   And make merry in the hall.
>   So I'll just take a peep inside!"
>   — Fie! he hits his head on hard stone!
>   Well, elf, had enough, have you?
>   Cuckoo! Cuckoo!

Some people however, also suggest that it might be Nyu, as opposed to Lucy. With the clock chiming in the *start* or maybe even *birth* of Nyu, into the world of normal humans.

Personally I think this was left open in a way it could be interpreted both in a positive and a negative ending. This both to drive people to read the manga [which has a slightly different story](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/779/1458) and to stay in line with the rhyme, as this can be interpreted in both a negative and a positive tone.

Answer (score 1):

In the final episode, after the clock scene, the dog starts making noise and then Kouta goes outside and sees a figure in the entrance of the house (that must be Lucy). So, it might be Lucy who used her invincible vectors to fix the clock from a distance and that shows us that her power somehow got enhanced (got longer vectors etc.).

Also, keep in mind that the only person who ever played with the clock in the anime was Nyu (the second personality of Lucy). So, the clock is related to Nyu.

And I conclude that by fixing the clock, it's the creator's way to make it clear to us that Lucy was alive and returned to the house of Kouta.

Answer (score 1):

So I stumbled onto a scene in the show that's seems like a easter egg and might debunk the ending which is left vague with mystery. So through out the whole show the grandfather clock is under the presumed assumption that it's broken at exactly 2:59:59. It's up for debate if it's pm or am but if trend holds up its a paradoxical concept which I'll elaborate it all up when I near the end of this but anyone bare with me. So if the grandfather clock was broken 1 second before the witching hour would seem symbolic already. But I'll debate that the clocks working perfectly fine and was never broken what so ever. Through the 13 episodes their's 1 scene where Kota is inside his house and you get a quick glimpse of the grandfather clock behind him showing the time of 1:29:23 (pm). Some will say it was a slip up. But if you per say "reverse engineer" the time using gematria you'll find many hidden meanings behind the time the grandfather clock says. But out of all results one stood out to me after hours of finding hundreds of results varying from Lucy's bday and the date all the events supposedly took place which none are given which gives more of a mysterious vibe to elfen lied. But the one result I saw was a single "Liebe Cicada" inside the time of 1:29:23. So this is where symbolism comes in. Kotas internal cicadian clock was broken from a traumatic loss of someone close to him, which when a cicadian clock is broken all times stops due to the insurmountable pain to that specific individual. Which the show is giving us the viewers the perception of kotas reality which has stopped to Kota and only Kota. "Kaede" using gematria you'll get the results of "starseed Lyran-Queen" which goes into plaidien fringe theory but I'll admit I'll keep an open mind knowing this show inspired stranger things. Keep an open mind. So if I'd go further in the theory basing my analysis off of the hidden number 1:29:23pm from the perfectly working clock Some will debate....well what about nyuu working on the clock. What if their just fitments of kotas imagination for coping mechanism of his deceased lover. When we find the date of events in the clocks hidden message you'll find a date in 1993. You look into the surrounding areas supposedly their were alien sightings or "paranormal encounters" but that parts only within speculation if this show was based off true events like stranger things as Eleven and Penny L A Shepard.  But thankfully elfen lied isn't as the time on the perfectly working clock was a coincidence probably. But knowing we will get all these results from the clocks hidden message of the time 1:29:23 shows something is more behind it than meets the eye of this "broken" grandfather clock. The individual who Kota lossed to break his cicadian clock to give the viewers interpretation the clock is broken is the same grave at the end of the Manga before....the twins. Or if we want to go by symbolism based on the name Kaede. 2 more plaidiens showed up to the grave. (Supposedly they exist on a frequent beyond ultraviolet as our eyes only see up to like 135 140hz or something in that range but also commonly their's reports of people with autism could see these "invisible entities". Hence the vectors.....(hmmmm I didn't think about that last part until now for the vectors being invisible beyond ultraviolet, I knew of plaidiens) but yaa anyone else reading this re watch the show play close attention for the grandfather clock showing 1:29:23 and see what you can figure out. Google says this fictional situation of elfen lied happened in 1994 without a birthday of lucy but I got a resul of 1993 April (I won't mention the date) of a event that had to do with paranormal alien encounters in Japan.....so based on that one scene where the clock isn't broken. It's Kota cicadian clock that is broken to make time seem like it stopped when that one scene shows the clocks working perfectly fine. Not based on true events....the liebe cicada kinda unfolded many questions about the grandfather clock showing 1:29:23. Maybe other people might get more answers and information from that specific time given to the audience to question. For the opening statement of the paradoxical concepts is with how they show the music box stops and grandfather clock starts moving and ticks to 3....pm after a late lunch when Kota got a knock on the door by a silhouette of Kaede/Lucy who is symbolic to plaidien "starseed Lyran-Queen". Which in theory they are Invisible beyond ultraviolet spectrum. Hence Imaginary friend label on him due to his cicadian clock is broken which depicts the broken grandfather clock but when you see the hidden message in the grandfather clock and find the liebe cicada you'll realize the grandfather clock isn't broken. Just like the grandfather clock and the music box....paradoxical concept. Sorry about the reiterating but my mind was blown last month after I found all this out. But don't take my word re watch it, find that time and see what anyone else will find in the numbers.....1:29:23. It was never broken....mind blown. Obviously the artists of the show could say it's a rushed move and no thought put in....except the liebe cicada resembling Kota kinda throws a wrench into the denial of this theory. I still got proof of work for the number results posted on other sites. Anyone else Wana see if I just blew the theory of nyuu fixing the (not) broken grandfather clock outa the water? Lol after almost 20 years we might have a breakthrough for our cliff hanger.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/71844)

Comment: Good observation about the witch hour, I didn't know of this term. Did you mean circadian clock? What is Liebe Cicada? I couldn't find in on google. And are Starseed and Lyran Queen popularized or originated from Star Trek? It'd helpful to link to, say, a Star Trek wiki for those not familiar with the franchise (not all anime fans are Americans or have heard of this world famous series). Likewise for Pleiadians (or Nordic aliens). Please try to edit the post correcting spelling mistakes and split it into readable paragraphs (I think there's something good here). Otherwise, I'll have to do it.

Comment: As Gao asked, *please* break this up into paragraphs. This looks promising but it's insanely hard to read.

Comment: Gotcha I'll work on a rough draft and Include the math behind it over the next week give or take. Apologies for not breaking it up into paragraphs.

Comment: @AndrewUpham Hey there, it's been over a month since you posted this. Is your draft nearing fruition? Do you mind that I go on to edit this?